# restore soft delete child in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cascading-deletes, soft-delete

I am using laravel and I want to restore child when I restore parent
for example
I've removed a user
and every user has a shop
so shop was deleted with $cascadeDeletes and all child related to user
but when I want to restore user her/his shop won't restore

here is Shop Model

```
  protected $cascadeDeletes = ['ProductCategories' , 'products', 'slideshows', 'purchases', 'vouchers', 'brands', 'feedbacks', 'tags', 'subscribers', 'invoice', 'donwloadLinkRequests', 'stats', 'compares', 'wishlists', 'faqs','shopContact']
```

and User Model

```
  protected $cascadeDeletes = ['addresses', 'userInformation', 'wishlist', 'comments','compare', 'shop', 'purchases', 'cart'];
```

> ** I am using iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes so is there any way with this**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a listener for the user models `restoring` event and restore the related shop. In the user models boot function, add the following:

```
static::restoring(function($user) {
    $user->shop()->withTrashed()->first()->restore();
});
```

See [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events).

Comment: I am using iatstuti/laravel-cascade-soft-deletes so is there any way with this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that package.